# How to iterate a list of dictionary with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

Looping over list of dictionary results error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Changing:

```
for the_key, the_value in bucket.items():
```

to:

```
for the_key, the_value in bucket[0].items():
```

results the first element.  I would like to capture all elements

```
bucket = [{'Name:': 'Share-1', 'Region': 'ap-south-1'}, {'Name:': 'Share-2', 'Region': 'us-west-1'}]


for the_key, the_value in bucket.items():
    print(the_key, 'corresponds to', the_value)
```

Actual results:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Output wanted:

```
Name: Share-1
Region: ap-south-1

Name: Share-2
Region: us-west-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `bucket` is a list, not a `dict`, so you should iterate over it first, and for each `d`ict, iterate over it's `items`:

```
bucket = [{'Name:': 'Share-1', 'Region': 'ap-south-1'}, {'Name:': 'Share-2', 'Region': 'us-west-1'}]

for d in bucket:
    for the_key, the_value in d.items():
        print(the_key, 'corresponds to', the_value)
```

Output:

```
Name: corresponds to Share-1
Region corresponds to ap-south-1
Name: corresponds to Share-2
Region corresponds to us-west-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for dictionary in bucket:
    for key, val in dictionary.items():
        print(the_key, 'corresponds to', the_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data hast two layers, so you need two loops:

```
for dct in lst:
    for key, value in dct.items():
        print(f"{key}: {value}")
    print() # empty line between dicts
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do it in a more `functional` way, i like it more:

```
map(lambda x: print("name: {x}".format(x=x['Name:'])), bucket)
```

It's lazy, no `for` loops, and much more readable

Running on:

```
bucket = [{'Name:': 'Share-1', 'Region': 'ap-south-1'}, 
          {'Name:': 'Share-2', 'Region': 'us-west-1'}]
```

you'll get (of course you need to consume the `map`):

```
name: Share-1
name: Share-2
```